# PHP Com export excel with form controls (checkbox)

Tags: php, com

I have an Excel template.
I am using [PHP Com](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php) to load and write excel file.

But I don't know how to write a checkedbox in to a cell.

Please help me!

Comment: `PHPExcel` is a pure PHP library for working with spreadsheet files in PHP, it doesn't use PHP COM at all, so removing tag

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved! This is my code:

```
$book   = $excel->Workbooks->Open("c:\\test3.xls");
$sheet = $book->WorkSheets->Item("Sheet1");
$sheet->CheckBoxes("Check1")->Value=1;
```